# Wordpress + Flexslider + ACF Gallery plugin only works in localhost

Tags: javascript, wordpress, flexslider, advanced-custom-fields

I have a problem with the Flexslider+ACF Gallery plugin integration in Wordpress.

It's only working on localhost but not in the live server

http://www.tusenado.com/2014/08/25/prueba-galeria/

If you can see at the code the gallery is generated:

```
            <div class="flexslider">
            <ul class="slides">
                <li>
                    <img src="http://www.tusenado.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/rajoy02.jpg" alt="" />
                    <p></p>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="http://www.tusenado.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/rajoy01.jpg" alt="" />
                    <p></p>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="http://www.tusenado.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/rajoy03.jpg" alt="" />
                    <p></p>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

As I said, the error is only in the live server, in localhost works perfectly.

Any guesses?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Website unavailable.

Comment: This is, indeed, very hard to debug, since the website is down and your code sample is of the generated gallery, not the full code (including your ACF fields).